# How to select all columns but one column as userdefined values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Can we select all table column by its original name but one column as usedefined name .i.e

```
select * from tbl_user_info LEFT JOIN tbl_user on 
tbl_user_info.user_id=tbl_user.id  
where tbl_user.user_type_id='2' ORDER BY tbl_user.id DESC
```

But i want something like this if possible

```
select *,IsActive as userstatus from tbl_user_info LEFT JOIN tbl_user on 
tbl_user_info.user_id=tbl_user.id 
where tbl_user.user_type_id='2' ORDER BY tbl_user.id DESC
```

or is their any other way to achieve it

Comment: Your query really doesn't make sense (you are using a `left join`, but filtering on the join condition).  Provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it by below way.

```
SELECT tbl_user_info.*,tbl_user.*,tbl_user.IsActive as userstatus 
FROM tbl_user_info 
LEFT JOIN tbl_user
ON tbl_user_info.user_id=tbl_user.id 
WHERE tbl_user.user_type_id='2' 
ORDER BY tbl_user.id DESC
```

Hope it will help you :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below:

```
SELECT *, 'IsActive' as userstatus 
FROM tbl_user_info 
LEFT JOIN tbl_user ON
tbl_user_info.user_id=tbl_user.id 
WHERE tbl_user.user_type_id='2' 
ORDER BY tbl_user.id DESC;
```

Simply wrap your value in quotes - '*value*' and asign the name of column like alias - `as yourColumnName`

Comment: i've written values in isactive column as 1 or 0 and when i write your query it shows username column but values in it are written as 'isactive' instead of 1 or 0

Answer (score 0):

Very simple.

```
SELECT *,
       'isUserVariable' AS newvarialbe 
  FROM tbl_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `alias`.

Also, your `where` condition and `order by` is on `tbl_user` table. So preferably you should `select` from `tbl_user` table and do `left join` on `tbl_user_info` like this.

```
select *, `IsActive` as userstatus 
from tbl_user left join tbl_user_info 
on tbl_user_info.user_id = tbl_user.id 
where tbl_user.user_type_id = '2' 
order by tbl_user.id DESC
```